# Como pudiera optimizar este código en C

Tags: c

Buen día!

Me estoy adentrando en el ambiente de la programación, estoy empezando a indagar en el lenguaje C, hice un programa sencillo que toma cinco valores, los muestra, los suma y finalmente los promedia, dependiente el rango del resultado del promedio muestra un mensaje. La cuestión aquí es como pudiera optimizar el programa. A continuación les anexo el código

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

  int a, b, c, d, e; //Los valores de las cinco variables
  int sum;
  float r= 5.0;
  float prom;

 //Toma y muestra un valor para a
  printf("Ingrese el valor de a: \n");
  scanf("%d", &a);
  //Mientras el numero dado sea mayor a el bucle while se seguirá ejecutando
    while(a>10){
        printf("El valor de a no debe ser mayor a 10, ingrese nuevamante: \n");
        scanf("%d", &a);
    }
  //Si se cumple la condición muestra el siguiente mensaje
    if(a>=1 && a<=10){
        printf("El valor de a es: %d\n", a);
      }

 //Toma y muestra un valor para b
  printf("Ingrese el valor de b: \n");
  scanf("%d", &b);
  //Mientras el numero dado sea mayor a el bucle while se seguirá ejecutando
    while(b>10){
        printf("El valor de b no debe ser mayor a 10, ingrese nuevamante: \n");
        scanf("%d", &b);
    }
  //Si se cumple la condición muestra el siguiente mensaje
    if(b>=1 && b<=10){
        printf("El valor de a es: %d\n", b);
      }

  //Toma y muestra un valor para c
  printf("Ingrese el valor de c: \n");
  scanf("%d", &c);
  //Mientras el numero dado sea mayor a el bucle while se seguirá ejecutando
    while(c>10){
        printf("El valor de c no debe ser mayor a 10, ingrese nuevamante: \n");
        scanf("%d", &c);
    }
  //Si se cumple la condición muestra el siguiente mensaje
    if(c>=1 && c<=10){
        printf("El valor de a es: %d\n", c);
      }

   //Toma y muestra un valor para d
  printf("Ingrese el valor de d: \n");
  scanf("%d", &d);
  //Mientras el numero dado sea mayor a el bucle while se seguirá ejecutando
    while(d>10){
        printf("El valor de d no debe ser mayor a 10, ingrese nuevamante: \n");
        scanf("%d", &d);
    }
  //Si se cumple la condición muestra el siguiente mensaje
    if(d>=1 && d<=10){
        printf("El valor de a es: %d\n", d);
      }

    //Toma y muestra un valor para e
  printf("Ingrese el valor de e: \n");
  scanf("%d", &e);
  //Mientras el numero dado sea mayor a el bucle while se seguirá ejecutando
    while(e>10){
        printf("El valor de e no debe ser mayor a 10, ingrese nuevamante: \n");
        scanf("%d", &e);
    }
  //Si se cumple la condición muestra el siguiente mensaje
    if(e>=1 && e<=10){
        printf("El valor de a es: %d\n", e);
      }

//Suma de las variables
  sum = a+b+c+d+e;
  printf("La suma de los valores es: %d\n", sum);
 //Division de las variables
  prom= sum / r;
  printf("El promedio de la suma es: %f\n", prom);

  if(prom<=5){
      printf("Reprobado \n");
      }else{
          printf("Aprobado \n");
      }

  return 0;
}
```

Me gustaría saber su opinión en cuanto a maneras de optimizarlo, ninguna en especifico, simplemente tengo la inquietud de como pudiera hacer el mismo funcionamiento con menos linea de código, ya que como se aprecia en el código se repite la misma operación cinco veces, lo intenté hacer con un ciclo for, pero sin éxito!

Sin más por el momento, espero su valiosa aportación.

Saludos!

Comment: Una forma simple de evitar repetición es sacar el código repetido a una función.  Puedes hacer la función independiente de la variable a leer, haciendo que reciba como parámetro el nombre de la variable (para poder mostrarlo al usuario cuando dice "Ingrese el valor de a") y que retorne como resultado el valor leido (para que el programa principal lo asigne a una variable distinta cada vez). El programa principal aún tendrá que llamar 5 veces a esta función, una por variable, pero habrá menos código repetido. Para usar un bucle deberías tener un array en vez de 5 variables separadas.

Comment: Cuando dices optimizar... ¿a qué te refieres exactamente? ¿Que el programa tenga menos instrucciones? ¿Que consuma menos memoria? ¿Que su tiempo de ejecución sea menor? ¿?

Comment: a) Menos líneas de código no significa necesariamente más óptimo. b) Generalmente el esfuerzo de optimización requiere que el código se pueda ejecutar muchas veces, para poder realizar comparaciones y generalmente se optimiza el código que se va a ejecutar muchas veces. c) La manera en la que está escrita la pregunta es una solicitud de opiniones, y las preguntas cuyas respuestas están basadas en opiniones no son permitidas en StackOverflow.

Comment: @jachguate, el punto *a* es discutible. Optimización es un concepto genérico que simplemente significa *mejorar algo*. En un equipo empotrado la optimización de software puede ir perfectamente orientada a reducir su tamaño.

Comment: @eferion, estoy con vos, realmente significa _encontrar la mejor manera_ de realizar algo y entiendo que hay casos en los que se va a buscar el menor tamaño posible, generalmente, del código objeto y no tanto del fuente. Si re-lees mi comentario anterior, ves que utilizo la frase **_no ... necesariamente_**, dejando abierta la puerta a que una mejora a la pregunta nos aclare que realmente es el tamaño del código lo que importa y no, por ejemplo, su tiempo de ejecución, que suele ser lo que más comunmente se busca al hablar de optimización.

Comment: 0


como comenté en la publicación apenas me estoy adentrando en el ambito de la programación, las respuestas que tengo de su parte las tomo como retroalimentación. A lo que me quise referir en la publicación es como pudiera obtener el mismo funcionamiento del código anexo con menos instrucciones, por ende con menos lineas de código, ya que el tiempo de ejecución que tiene el código anexo es rápida. Agradezco de su apoyo y quedo pendiente de sus dudas y/o comentarios. Saludos!

Answer (score 2):

- Creo deberías pensar en encapsular trozos de tu código
- Teniendo en mente separarlo en archivos para luego llamarlos como librería de tu autoría.
- Juega a poner todo dentro de estructuras ( `array, clases y funciones`) fuera de `main`, para sólo llamarlas desde allí.
- Eso te va a permitir asomarte a otros recurso `:punteros`, trabajo con archivos y base de datos.